# Unable to change object settings and system settings for a Marketing User profile

Tags: profile, sandbox

Ok, this would seem as a very stupid problem but I have no reason why it happening.

I am in a Developer Pro Sandbox logged in as System Administrator. I need to change the create/edit permissions for account and contacts and also disable the "View the App Setup and Administrative Settings pages" for the Marketing User profile.

However when I go to the profile and respective tabs, the checkboxes for those settings are locked in (disabled).

[image]

You can see above the Read, Create, Edit, Delete checkboxes are disabled so I cant change those permissions.

[image]

The View the App Setup and Administrative Settings checkbox is also disabled.

Is it because of the fact that I am in a Developer Pro Sandbox so it won't let me change these settings for other profiles?

Comment: This is an OOTB Profile and you are limited in the changes that can be done; common practice is to clone Marketing Profile and call it `MyCompany Marketing Profile`. Or, use another profile with limited features/permissions and extend with permission sets - assigning users to the permission sets

Comment: Thank you. I had forgotten about these standard profiles and kept wondering what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

This is an OOTB Profile and you are limited in the changes that can be done;

Common practice is to clone `Marketing Profile` and call it `MyCompany Marketing Profile`.

Or, use another profile with limited features/permissions and extend with permission sets that grant the relevant Marketing Profile permissions - then assign users to the permission sets.